# Magento to salesforce integration

Tags: rest, magento, soap, salesforce, integration

I have a magento  ecommerce web application want to sync my data from magento to salesforce and vice versa
I thought this would be as simple as collecting their salesforce.com credentials to open a connection to salesforce.com and pull down their customer,product and contact.
But it does not look that easy! For one, I cannot find a global API. Apparently, each salesforce.com company has to "generate" their own WSDLs .Don’t have much idea on rest api, where I don’t  have to generate wsdl for each different company.
I have done lots of research on this could not find any proper solution Most of the vendors are using soap api where I need to follow same process that is every time I need to generate WSDLs for each company…

Answer (score 0):

Each company is different that's why you need to generate a different structure.
I would recommend this solution: https://products.crunchyconsulting.com/crunchy-products/crunchy-magforce.html with some customizations available if you ask for it.